# in this higher level function, where does the argument, n come from?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

In the following code from [ch 5 of Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net//05_higher_order.html), where does that value of the argument n come from?

Why does this function return *anything*.  I guess, I hate to ask a unspecific, cliche question, but I am baffled:  How does this function work?

```js
function unless(test, then) {
  if (!test) then();
}
function repeat(times, body) {
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) body(i);
}

repeat(3, function(n) {
  unless(n % 2, function() {
    console.log(n, "is even");
  });
});
// → 0 is even
// → 2 is even
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see `n` is defined as a parameter in the callback here:

```
repeat(3, function(n) {
//                 ^
```

Let's go into the `repeat` function:

```
function repeat(times, body) {
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) body(i);
    // We're calling our callback with i ^
}
```

Here `times` will be `3` and `body` will be our anonymous function (callback). Hence when we call `body(i)` we *actually* call the following (switched `n` out with `i`, as we're calling `body(i)`):

```
unless(i % 2, function() {
    console.log(i, "is even");
})
```

---

Here's your entire source unwrapped:

```
var times = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    var n = i; // We're renaming "i" (from body(i)) to "n" (in function(n))

    if (!(n % 2)) {
        console.log(n, "is even");
    }
}
```

Comment: Question.  for i = 1, n % 2 = 1.  Does that 1 convert to "true" in the "test" part of the "unless" function?

Comment: @Goodword It doesn't, but javascript has a huge range of things it considers [truthy or falsy](http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/). As you can see from this table `0` is falsy and hence matches `if (!test)`. `if (foo)` is the same as `if (foo == true)`. To prove the logic we can iterate through and calculate the equations ourselves: `0 % 2 = 0` (falsy - show), `1 % 2 = 1` (truthy - don't show), `2 % 2 = 0` (falsy -show).

Answer (score 0):

The variable n is defined in the callback method you are passing to "repeat":

```
repeat(3,function(n){
```

unless otherwise modified inside that callback function (or defined using "var n = ..." that value will persist in the scope all the way to the console.log call.